# Dr. Racket, help getting element from a list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I am working on a finite state machine in Dr. Racket, and need some help extracting the next state in my transition function.

Right now, I am not checking to make sure the chars in the string match the alphabet, or that the final state is in the list of final states, or any of that until I can get the transition from state to state recursively.

Here is where I am at right now:

```
#lang racket
(require math/array)

(define in_string (list "a" "b" "b" "b"))
(define alphabet (list "a" "b"))
(define initial_state 0)
(define final_states (list 2))
(define delta_fn (list
                       (list 0 "a" 0)
                       (list 0 "b" 1)
                       (list 1 "a" 0)
                       (list 1 "b" 1)))

(define current_state initial_state)

(define (transition current_state in_string delta_fn)
  (writeln current_state)
  (writeln in_string)
  (writeln delta_fn)
  (cond
    [(empty? in_string) (writeln current_state)]
    [else
     (let ([input (car in_string)])
       (set! current_state (filter (lambda (v)
                                     (match v
                                       [(list (== current_state) (== input) _) #t]
                                       [_ #f]))
                                   delta_fn)))
     (writeln current_state)]
     ;(transition current_state in_string delta_fn)]
    )
  )
```

So at the moment, if you run this script and the type: (transition current_state in_string delta_fn), you will get the following output:

```
> (transition current_state in_string delta_fn)
0
("a" "b" "b" "b")
((0 "a" 0) (0 "b" 1) (1 "a" 0) (1 "b" 1))
((0 "a" 0))
```

That last line: ((0 "a" 0)) is a result of the (writeln current_state) command after the lambda function runs to find its match in the delta_fn list.  I thought I could just type (cdr (cdr current_state)) right there to get the third item in that output, but ((0 "a" 0)) is not a list and I can't operate on it like a list.

So my question is: what is ((0 "a" 0))?  Why is current_state set to that instead of '(0 "a" 0)?

Any help would be greatly appreciate, please know that I am very new to functional programming in general, so use small words =P

---

Solution!

```
(define (transition current_state in_string delta_fn)
  (cond
    [(empty? in_string) (writeln current_state)]
    [else
     (let ([input (car in_string)])
       (set! filtered_delta_fn (filter (lambda (v)
                                     (match v
                                       [(list (== current_state) (== input) _) #t]
                                       [_ #f]))
                                   delta_fn)))
     (set! next_state (car (cdr (cdr (car filtered_delta_fn)))))
     (transition next_state (cdr in_string) delta_fn)]
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the variable `current_state`. Don't do that!

First it was 0, the initial state.

Then you change it to hold a totally different value, the result of `filter` operation. Instead, use some temporary variable for that, so `current_state` is not changed yet.

Now, `filter` returns that value you ask about,  `((0 "a" 0))`, because of all the entries in the `delta_fn` it kept the one matching your criterion, the list `(0 "a" 0)`. So the filtered list holds one matching entry in it.

To find your next state from it, simply call

```
(set! next_state (car (cdr (cdr (car filtered_delta_fn)))))
;                                (0 "a" 0)
;                           ("a" 0)
;                      (0)
;                 0
```

where `filtered_delta_fn` will be the temporary variable mentioned above.

Then, the recursive call will now be

```
(transition next_state in_string delta_fn)
```

You could use `current_state` in place of `next_state`, but that's just messy. Much better to have all your variables meaningful, with proper values corresponding to their meaning. Otherwise, it is easy to quickly get lost in all the complex confusion.

Also, the use of `set!` is usually frowned upon. In Scheme we usually declare a new variable to be used henceforth, like

```
    (let ((next_state (car (cdr ..... ))))
        ; recursive call .....
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked well for me, now I can use the function "transition" to get the final state my fsm will be in, and now I can check if that is an acceptable state.  I updated my code to reflect your guidance.  I will change set! to let as my next exercise!